# difference between case f:Int and case f @ Int

Tags: scala

what is the difference between `case x:Int` and `case x @ Int`? In the following example, why doesn't `case x@Int` gets matched when an `Int` argument is passed?

```
scala> def matchInt (x:Any) = x match {
     | case x:Int => println("got int"+x) //this matches with Int
     | case _ => println("no int "+x)
     | }
matchInt: (x: Any)Unit

scala> matchInt(1)
got int1

scala> matchInt("2")
no int 2

scala> def matchInt (x:Any) = x match {
     | case x @ Int => println("got int"+x) //this doesn't matches with Int
     | case _ => println("no int "+x)
     | }
matchInt: (x: Any)Unit

scala> matchInt("2")
no int 2

scala> matchInt(1)
no int 1

scala>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `x: Int` for Type pattern matching and at times you may want to add a variable to a pattern. You can do this with the following general syntax: `variableName @ pattern`.

1. For `x: Int` your pattern matching is fine to match the type of the x.
2. For `variableName @ pattern`, look the example where we are matching a various pattern:

   ```
   scala> case class Test(t1: String, t2: String)
   defined class Test

   scala> object Test2 extends App {
            |   def matchType(x: Any): String = x match {
            |     case y @ List(1, _*) => s"$y"   // works; prints the list
            |     case y @ Some(_) => s"$y"   // works, returns "Some(Hiii)"
            |     case y @ Test("t1", "t2") => s"$y"  // works, returns "Test(t1,t2)"
            |   }
            | }
   defined object Test2

   scala>  Test2.matchType(List(1,2,3))
   res2: String = List(1, 2, 3)

   scala> Test2.matchType(Some("Hiii"))
   res3: String = Some(Hiii)

   scala> Test2.matchType(Test("t1","t2"))
   res4: String = Test(t1,t2)
   ```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ManuChadha Now you can see.

Answer (score 2):

`x:Int` means "x of type Int". `x@Int` means "x that *is* a type Int". 
The latter is pretty useless in this case.

Comment: So `x` is an object in `x:Int`. Got that. What is `x` in `x@Int`? Where do I use `x@Int`? Could a variable `be a type` instead of being an `object of a type`?

Comment: `x` is not an object. It is a variable. In the first case you declare that any variable of type `Int` will match. The second case only matches a variable that _is_ a type `Int`. Yes, a variable can be assigned a type. No, it is not useful in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose this is how I'll use it `scala> matchInt(scala.Int)
got intobject scala.Int

scala> matchInt(scala.Float)
no int object scala.Float`

Comment: Yes, but for that you don't need `x` :) Just `case Int => ...` would work.

Comment: Understood. Could you give a practical example of where `@` might be useful?

Comment: Maybe for some reason, I also want to store the type `Int` then I could store in it in a variable using `x@Int` notation. Though I cannot think of a real life usecase

Comment: In the first case you declare that any _value_ of type `Int` will match and get assigned to the variable `x`, not "that any variable of type `Int` will match".